# Convert CharCode to Char?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, character-encoding, char, character

## What I need

ok I googled this and there are many tutorials on how to get the charCode from the character but I cant seem to find out how to get the character from the charcode.

Basically I am I am listening for the `KeyDown` event on a `TextInput`.

I prevent the char from being typed via `event.preventDefault();`

Later I need to add the text-char to the TextInput.

I can get the charCode via `event.charCode` so if I can turn that into a string I can save it for later user.

## Why I need it

Basically I am making a TextInput, that that I can set to display default text in it. When A user types into it, I want to remove the default text first then add the user typed text.

Currently I am either removing it all, or ending up with both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's simple:

```
var yourNewChar:String = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
```